# Numpy randint appending

Tags: python, random, numpy, numbers, append

So im generating a random list with numpy named heights...

```
heights = random.randint(10, size=random.randint(20))
```

Im using this list for testing purposes, but I have one condition, I need to append to the list the 1st number every time it generates.  Basically i need to always create 2 of the first digit, for any random list generated.
So if the list looks like:

```
[1 2 2 5 5 6 7 7 7 9]
```

I need it to look like:

```
[1 2 2 5 5 6 7 7 7 9 1]
```

I tried using

```
heights.append(heights[0])
```

But im getting an error.
This works with lists, but not numpy:/

Comment: `random.randint(20)` can be 0. So `heights` can be of zero length. In that case, what item (if any) do you want appended to `heights`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `np.concatenate()` or `np.hsatck()`:

```
heights = np.concatenate((heights, heights[0:1]))
```

or

```
heights = np.hstack((heights, heights[0:1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
heights = np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(1,21)); heights[-1] = heights[0]
```

Pre-allocating an array of the right size is much faster than using `np.append`, `np.concatenate`, or `np.hstack`:

```
In [100]: %timeit heights = np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(1,21)); heights[-1] = heights[0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.93 us per loop

In [99]: %timeit heights = np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(1,20)); heights = np.append(heights, heights[0])
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.24 us per loop

In [104]: %timeit heights = np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(1,20)); heights = np.concatenate((heights, heights[0:1]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.74 us per loop

In [105]: %timeit heights = np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(1,20)); heights = np.hstack((heights, heights[0:1]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.31 us per loop
```

Comment: I need to always create 2 of the first digit, for any random list generated, not just for the one i used as in example.

Comment: In that case, use `heights[-1] = heights[0]`.

Comment: It is interesting that concatenate and hstack have such a large difference in timings, do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: @ophion: `np.concatenate` is [written entirely in C](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2062), while `np.hstack` [first calls some Python code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L230).